# Installing yii2-adldap-module

Tags: yii2, adldap

I am trying to install yii2-adldap-module by following the steps in https://github.com/edvler/yii2-adldap-module . When I try to install it by `php composer.phar require edvlerblog/yii2-adldap-module "v1.0.0"`, I am getting the following error

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for edvlerblog/yii2-adldap-module v1.0.0 -> satisfiable by edvlerblog/yii2-adldap-module[v1.0.0].
    - edvlerblog/yii2-adldap-module v1.0.0 requires adldap/adldap v4.0-stable -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

How can Install adldap for yii2? Is there any other way or the extension is still in use ?

Answer (score 1):

```
"edvlerblog/yii2-adldap-module": "^4.0.0"
```

add this to composer.json and run `composer update`

Comment: or using `"edvlerblog/yii2-adldap-module": "dev-master"` dev-master version this working always

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the extension - [take a look](https://github.com/edvler/yii2-adldap-module/issues/8):

Basically, the adldap module is no longer maintained, and so the dependencies of the Yii2 module need to be changed to using a fork of the adldap module.

You can probably work around this by forking the Yii2 module and perhaps even submit a pull request to get it fixed. ;)

Answer (score 0):

[edvler/yii2-adldap-module](https://github.com/edvler/yii2-adldap-module) is just a proxy class. It has some errors since the [adldap/adLDAP](https://github.com/adldap/adldap) package is no longer maintained. Looks like edvler extension in no longer maintained too.

You can rewrite it using [Adldap2/Adldap2](https://github.com/adldap2/adldap2) package or use my extension instead: https://github.com/alexeevdv/yii2-adldap